# Error starting Spark in EMR 4.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I created an `EMR 4.0` instance in AWS with all available applications, including `Spark`. I did it manually, through AWS Console. I started the cluster and SSHed to the master node when it was up. There I ran `pyspark`. I am getting the following error when `pyspark` tries to create `SparkContext`:

> 2015-09-03 19:36:04,195 ERROR Thread-3 spark.SparkContext
>   (Logging.scala:logError(96)) - -ec2-user, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x at
>
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)

I haven't added any custom applications, nor bootstrapping and expected everything to work without errors. Not sure what's going on. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Login as the user "hadoop" (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-master-node-ssh.html). It has all the proper environment and related settings for working as expected.  The error you are receiving is due to logging in as "ec2-user".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Spark on EMR this week, and found a few weird things relating to user permissions and relative paths.

It seems that running Spark from a directory which you don't 'own', as a user, is problematic. In some situations Spark (or some of the underlying Java pieces) want to create files or folders, and they think that `pwd` - the current directory - is the best place to do that.

Try going to the home directory

```
cd ~
```

then running `pyspark`.